# Python XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to read an XML file using lxml but I keep receiving this error:

```
XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

my code:

```
import lxml
parser16= lxml.etree.XMLParser(encoding = "utf-16")
tree = lxml.etree.parse(input_filepath, parser = parser16)
```

XML file header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<LoanResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <encompassId>b100ab9f-444-5555-949c-1873ed1ddeb3</encompassId>
  <adverseActionDate>2018-06-20T00:00:00Z</adverseActionDate>
  <applications>
    <Application>
      <id>_borrower1</id>
      <applicationId>_borrower1</applicationId>
      <applicationIndex>0</applicationIndex>
      <assets>
        <Asset>
          <id>Asset/0</id>
          <assetType>LifeInsurance</assetType>
          <borrowerId>_borrower1</borrowerId>
          <isEmpty>true</isEmpty>
        </Asset>
```

Error:

```
XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Appreciate any help / input in resolving.

Comment: The file may begin with a byte-order mark.

Comment: Can you edit that sample to close the xml tags. In fact you could remove a fair number of the tags because the error is at the start.

Comment: How about `print(open(input_filepath, 'rb').read(80))` so we can see that the byte format is?

Comment: Instead of a parser specifically declared utf-16, try `tree = lxml.etree.parse(input_filepath)`. lxml should read the xml declaration and figure out the encoding.

Comment: `print(open(input_filepath, 'rb').read(80))`

gives the following:

`b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>\r\n<LoanResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.' `

Comment: trying code as `tree - lxml.etree.parse(input_file_path)` gives this error: `XMLSyntaxError: Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content, line 1, column 38` which is weird since the XML file explicitly states `utf-16 `...

Comment: As an update, got this to work by explicitly setting parser to `utf-8` despite file stating `utf-16`.  Final code as: `tree = lxml.etree.parse(input_filepath, parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(encoding = "utf-8"))`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that the encoding was guessed by the editor as UTF-8 with BOM saving it using simple UTF-8 solved the issue.